# Why kendo.observable do not read datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-mvvm

Could you explain why kendo ui observable do not read data source when bind to html ?

I based my code on this example : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/remote-binding

I don't understand the link between the dropdown and the observable.

```
InitObservable = function (Id) {
viewModel = kendo.observable({
    //create a dataSource
    tacheDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        autoSync: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: function () {
                    return crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Taches?ID=" + Id;
                },
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            }
            ,
            update: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Taches",
                method: "PATCH",
                dataType: "json"
            }
            ,
            destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Taches/Destroy",
                dataType: "json"
            }
            ,
            create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Taches",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            }
            ,
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: TacheFields
            }
        }
    }), // endDatasource
    selectedTache: null, //this field will contain the edited dataItem
    hasChange: false,
    save: function (e) {
        this.tacheDataSource.sync();
        this.set("hasChange", false);
    },
    remove: function () {
        if (confirm("Etes vous sûr(e) de vouloir supprimer cette tâche ?")) {
            this.tacheDataSource.remove(this.selectedTache);
            this.set("selectedTache", this.tacheDataSource.view()[0]);
            this.change();
        }
    },
    showForm: function () {
        return this.get("selectedTache") !== null;
    },
    change: function () {
        this.set("hasChanges", true);
    }//,
    //cancel: function () {
    //    this.dataSource.cancelChanges(); //calcel all the change
    //    validator.hideMessages(); //hide the warning messages
    //    $("#tacheWindow").data("kendoWindow").close();
    //}
});
kendo.bind($("#tacheWindow"), viewModel);
}
```

I tested the datasource alone with datasource.read(), it works.

What is the trigger of the read of the datasource ?

----- New details

I added

```
type: "odata-v4"
```

in the datasource and I updated the schema as this :

```
e
schema: {
            data:function(data){
                var toReturn = data.value;
                return toReturn;
            },
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: TacheFields
            }
        }
```

And this to force read()

```
viewModel.selectedTache = proprietesEcranTache.tacheId;
if (viewModel.showForm()) {
    viewModel.tacheDataSource.read();
    kendo.bind($("#tacheWindow"), viewModel);
}
```

I see my answer in network debugger of chrome and I know I receive data in the form witout error but no data are displayed.

Here the oData answer

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://localhost:14986/odata/$metadata#Taches","value":
    [
        {
        "ID":1,"Description":"D\u00e9marrage application","CreateurId":7,"TypeTacheID":1,"EtatTacheID":6,"ValidantId":null,"DateValidation":null,"EstValidee":false,"CommentaireValidation":null,"EvennementPrecedentID":null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my form

```
<div id="tacheWindow">
<form id="TacheForm">
    <ul class="TacheFormFields">
        <li class="">
            <div class="formFieldTitle">Id</div>
            <div class="formFieldInput textField"><input id="tacheId" type="text" data-bind="value: ID" /></div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <div class="formFieldTitle">Type de tâche</div>
                <select id="typesTachesDdl" data-role="dropdownlist"
                        data-bind="value: TypeTacheID"
                        data-value-primitive="true"
                        data-text-field="Nom"
                        data-value-field="ID"></select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="formFieldTitle">Description</div>
                <div class="formFieldInput textField">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="formFieldTitle">Createur</div>
                <select id="CreateursDdl" data-role="dropdownlist"
                        data-bind="value: CreateurId"
                        data-value-primitive="true"
                        data-text-field="Nom"
                        data-value-field="ID"></select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="formFieldTitle">Validant</div>
                <select id="ValidantsDdl" data-role="dropdownlist"
                        data-bind="value: ValidantId"
                        data-value-primitive="true"
                        data-text-field="Nom"
                        data-value-field="ID"
                        disabled="disabled"></select>
            </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="dialog_buttons">
        <button id="TacheFormTemplateSave" data-bind="click: observableSave" class="k-button">Ok</button>
        <button id="TacheFormTemplateSave" data-bind="click: observableCancel" class="k-button">Annuler</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the datasource within your view model simply makes it observable and nothing more, as you have noted. It will only get read when passed to a kendo widget (such as a DropDownList). The telerik demo shows this within the bound html container:

```
<select data-role="dropdownlist" data-option-label="Select product"
        data-value-field="ProductID" data-text-field="ProductName"
        data-bind="source: productsSource, value: selectedProduct" style="width: 100%;"></select>
```

The kendo.bind statement scans the html container for elements with a data-role attribute. In the case above it will find data-role="dropdownlist", instantiate a DropDownList widget and add the necessary html elements for it to the DOM. This part of the declaration:

```
data-bind="source: productsSource"
```

...will search for a datasource named 'productsSource' within the view model and assign it to the DropDownList as its datasource to use. The DropDownList will then trigger a read of that datasource in order to populate itself with data.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple sample that works

```
Home Page
<div id="editForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Nom</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input data-role="dropdownlist"
                       data-auto-bind="false"
                       data-text-field="Nom"
                       data-value-field="ID"
                       data-bind="value: selectedPerson,
                              source: persons,
                              visible: isVisible,
                              enabled: isEnabled,
                              events: {
                                change: onChange
                              }"
                       style="width: 200px;" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" data-value-update="displaySelectedPerson" data-bind="value: selectedPerson.Nom" class="k-textbox"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Important detail : in the text box : data-bind="value: selectedPerson.Nom"

This allow observable to update the field.

Javascript :

```
var persons = [
    { ID: "1", Nom: "Lolo" },
    { ID: "2", Nom: "Toto" }
];

documentReady = function () {
    var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
        personsSource: persons
        , persons: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: persons,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "number" }
                        , Nom: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        , selectedPerson: null
        , hasChange : false
        , isPrimitive: false
        , isVisible: true
        , isEnabled: true
        , primitiveChanged: function () {
            this.set("selectedPerson", null);
        }
        , onChange: function () {
            console.log("event :: change (" + this.displaySelectedPerson() +          ")");
        }
        , displaySelectedPerson: function () {
            var selectedPerson = this.get("selectedPerson");
            return kendo.stringify(selectedPerson, null, 4);
        }
    });
    kendo.bind($("#editForm"), viewModel);
}
```